# Why my NDVI animation using GEE is strange

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis, smoothing

I would like to show an NDVI animation of some Amazon area to demonstrate the deforest effects.

Here is my high-level code.

1. Get the NDVI from MODIS data and only use the images from Sept and December for the last 22 years. The purpose of using Sept and Dec images is to use the same dry season to eliminate seasonal noises.
2. For the image in the same year during Sept and Dec, reduce the image collection with Median reducer. Then I got 22 images.
3. Create GIF to show the reduced images.

The final GIF is here (https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/videoThumbnails/af07825e78dd78a7615e8426dd3f8848-499314c89d8336cabf2897fce6fc0d2b:getPixels)

I noticed that the dramatic yellow color changes on the left hand sides of the gif over these years. It seems strange to me.

Did I miss anything?

```
var roi = geometry; //ee.Geometry.Polygon( [-69, 1.232, -50, 1.243, -50, -7, -69, -7]);

// Define a mask to clip the NDVI data by.
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'BR'));

var region = roi;


var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A2').filterBounds(region).select('NDVI');

col = col.map(function(img) {
  var start_date = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'));
  var year =start_date.get('year');
  var doy = start_date.getRelative('day', 'year');
  var month = start_date.getRelative('month', 'year');
  return img.set('year', year, 'month', month, 'doy', doy);
});

col = col.filter(ee.Filter.rangeContains('month', 9, 12));
print(col);
var distinctYear = col.distinct('year');

var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'year', rightField: 'year'});

// Define a join.
var join = ee.Join.saveAll('year_matches');

var postJoin = join.apply(distinctYear, col, filter);
print(postJoin);

// Apply the join and convert the resulting FeatureCollection to an
// ImageCollection.
var joinCol = ee.ImageCollection(postJoin);

// Apply median reduction among matching DOY collections.
var comp = joinCol.map(function(img) {
  var yearCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    img.get('year_matches')
  );
  var reducedImage = yearCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
  return reducedImage.set('year', img.get('year'));
});

print(comp);

// Define RGB visualization parameters.
var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 9000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

// Import gena's package which allows text overlay on image
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text'); 

var annotations = [
  {position: 'left', offset: '1%', margin: '1%', property: 'label', scale: Map.getScale() * 2} ]

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
var rgbVis = comp.map(function(img) {
  var image = img.visualize(visParams).clip(mask).set({'label': img.get('year')})
  
  // create a new image with the label overlayed using gena's package
  var annotated = text.annotateImage(image, {}, region, annotations); 

  return annotated;
});


// Define GIF visualization parameters.
var gifParams = {
  'region': region,
  'dimensions': 600,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 1
};

// Print the GIF URL to the console.
print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));

// Render the GIF animation in the console.
print(ui.Thumbnail(rgbVis, gifParams));
```